# Ajax call returning my HTML page instead of JsonResult?

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-core, datatable, razor-pages

(I'm using ASP.NET Core razor pages) I have a JsonResult method:

```cs
public JsonResult OnPostloadListJson()
        {
            vwOpenRequests = _context.vwOpenRequests.ToList();
            return new JsonResult(vwOpenRequests);

            //var items = _context.vwOpenRequests.ToList();
            //IList<vwOpenRequest> resultList = new List<vwOpenRequest>();
            //for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
            //{
            //    resultList.Add(items[i]);
            //}
            //return new JsonResult(resultList);
        }
```

Which I need pulled in via ajax call, for a DataTable:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mytable').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                //url: "?handler=loadListJson",
                url: "@Url.Page("/Index")?handler=loadListJson",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            },
            columns: [
                { data: "RequestTo" },
                { data: "SubGroup" },
                { data: "RequestDt" },
                { data: "DueDt" },
                { data: "Desc" },
                { data: "Reason" },
                { data: "LastUpdateDt" },
                { data: "RequestType" }
            ]
    });
});
```

This results in this error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" which led me to look at the JSON response being received... it's the HTML page for some reason, and my content-type is being defined as "text/html" as a result.

My table includes < thead > and < tr > elements with  headers, amounting in the same number of columns I'm attempting to pull. I've added a breakpoint to my JsonResult method and it isn't hitting it before throwing the error, even though my handler and url are properly named. What am I missing here?

Comment: Check the request link via the browser dev tools to see if it's correct and try `@Url.Page("/Index", "loadListJson")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and the same problem as yours appeared. After testing, I found that your code has three problems.

1:Routing

In your post action,your method should be `OnPostLoadListJson`instead of `OnPostloadListJson`,`l`should be capitalized.

In your ajax,`url`should be `url: "?handler=loadListJson",`

2:Modify your post method like below:

```
  public  JsonResult OnPostLoadListJson()
    {
      vwOpenRequests = _context.vwOpenRequests.ToList();

      return new JsonResult(new { data = vwOpenRequests });
    }
```

3:columns in your ajax should be:

```
columns: [
            { data: "requestTo" },
            { data: "subGroup" },
            { data: "requestDt" },
            { data: "dueDt" },
            { data: "desc" },
            { data: "reason" },
            { data: "lastUpdateDt" },
            { data: "requestType" }
        ]
```

The first letter of data should be lowercase.

Result:
[image]

Comment: You are a LIVESAVER! Thanks for being so helpful!